# SSRS - Sending multiple ID values in a parameter and generating a tablix row for each value in parameter

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting

**UPDATE**: Solution at bottom of post!

I have a report in SSRS that receives one parameter @ID and then generates the report. My task is to find out if it's somehow possible to pass multiple ID values at once inside one parameter and then generate a report for each of those values and place them all inside one PDF file. However, I want to know if it's possible to somehow pass a parameter that contains multiple number values (IDs) which would look like this, for ex. : @ID=1,2,3,4,5.

[image]

I would then place my report inside a tablix row or something like that and generate a row for each of those values I pass in parameter. In the end, I would have multiple "reports" generated inside one PDF.

Is something like this even possible to do in SSRS? Report is generated through a link sent to the report server and the link would include all IDs, preferably.

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**:

Came up with solution that works with passing multiple parameters. I've changed my query from this:

```
DECLARE @Sem_ID AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '137210;137211'

SELECT Sem_ID, Sem_KW, Sem_Jahr
FROM acc_seminar.t_Seminar
JOIN dbo.tbl_hotel h ON Sem_Ht_ID=h.pk_hotel
WHERE Sem_ID IN (SELECT value  
FROM fn_Split(@Sem_ID, ';')  
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '')
```

As you can see, I changed 'WHERE' clause to split @Sem_ID parameter to get int values where the delimiter is ' ; ' . After that, I can input multiple values in single parameter like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your Report go to your Parameter, Select Multiple Value Check box. When you preview your report it will show you an option of drop down list.

[Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2866/sql-server-reporting-services-using-multivalue-parameters/) you will find very good working example of your desired functionality

Comment: Hello, I've found the solution I needed, will update my OP.